# vb.net change location of 2 different texts in button

Tags: vb.net, winforms, button, text

I have a problem with another line of text in button. This code works fine but not how i want.
Another line of text displays on top of the button and i want to it display on bottom of the button.
Code:

```
Private Sub btnCheckPass_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles btnCheckPass.Paint
    Dim btn = DirectCast(sender, Button)
    Dim text = ("Skontrolujte silu vašich hesiel a ich prelomovosť")
    Dim smallFont As New Font(btn.Font.FontFamily, btn.Font.Size - 10)

    e.Graphics.DrawString(text.ToString(),
                          btn.Font,
                          Brushes.Gray,
                          New Rectangle(New Point(), btn.Size),
                          New StringFormat With {.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center})
End Sub
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Think all that's needed is is an off-set for the top of the text when you create the new rectangle.  What that off-set is really depends on what text your already displaying.  Perhaps a screenshot might help

Comment: See the StringFormat's `LineAlignment` property. You can also define a Rectangle that describes precisely the area where you want to draw this text. Probably an area below the center of your Button. -- Btw, you should build a Custom Control and override `OnPaint()`.

Comment: Thank you for your help, using ** LineAlignment ** the problem has been solved.